# Reusing a modal, in a React component, with different children

Tags: javascript, reactjs, modal-dialog

Recently i had to write something in React, that required me to render different components in a modal. Being that i didn't want to repeat my self with different modals in the same parent component, i decided to reuse it, but wasn't sure how to do it "correctly". This is what i have done:

```
  renderModalTitle = () => {
return this.state.currentModalAction === 'delete' ? `Are you sure you want to delete book "${this.state.currentBook.title}"?`
  : this.state.currentBook ? `Edit book "${this.state.currentBook.title}"`
    : 'Create new book'
}

renderModalBody = () => {
  return this.state.currentModalAction === 'edit' || 
   this.state.currentModalAction === 'new' ?
    <BookForm book={this.state.currentBook} onSave={this.onBookSave}> 
    </BookForm>
      : <ConfirmDelete onBookDeleteCancel={this.toggle} onBookDelete={()=> 
      {this.onBookDelete(this.state.currentBook.id)}} data= 
    {this.state.currentBook}></ConfirmDelete>

 }
```

I know it's a bit hard to read, because the indentation in the code snippet is slightly messed up. But as you can see, i just have functions that return the relevant jsx, according to the "currentModalAction". Then in the modal:

```
 <Modal isOpen={this.state.modal} toggle={this.toggle} className={this.props.className}>
        <ModalHeader className="color_main" toggle={this.toggle}>{this.renderModalTitle()}</ModalHeader>
        <ModalBody>
          {this.renderModalBody()}
        </ModalBody>
        <ModalFooter>

          <Button className="square" color="default" onClick={this.toggle}>Cancel</Button>
        </ModalFooter>
      </Modal>
```

So yes, i've achieved "reusability" of the modal, and didn't repeat my self, but it seems to me, that this might do more harm than good...Not vert readable, not very clear.

Is there some common approach towards this issue? Notice that i didn't use react-modal or something like that. It's just reactstrap.

Comment: Have you tried using [children](https://reactjs.org/docs/composition-vs-inheritance.html)? I can't duplicate it right now, but I remember using a modal that was essentially: `modalRendered && <Modal closeModal={this.closeModal}><NestedComponent/></Modal>`, where Modal `render(){ <div><button onClick={this.props.closeModal}/>{this.props.children.firstOrDefault()}</div>}`

Comment: But wouldn't i still need to make the same logical operations, to decide which children are passed?

Comment: I would've formatted this by rendering in the parent that holds the modals like this: 
`render(){
  return (
    <div>
      <OtherStuff/>
      { editModalRendered &&
        <Modal>
          <EditBody/>
        </Modal>}
      { deleteMod...
    </div>
  );
}`
A bit of repetition, but it also allows you to make the contents of the modal completely separate components if you'd like.

Comment: It didn't let me format that like I wanted to :(

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I made some code representing your case.

Your can use a function prop like `renderBodyComponent` that will render your modal body.

```js
class FlexibleModal extends React.Component {
  render() {
    if (!this.props.isOpen) {
      return null;
    }
 
    return (
      <div className="flexible-modal">
        <div className="flexible-modal-header">
          {this.props.headerTitle}
        </div>
        <div className="flexible-modal-body">
          {this.props.renderBodyComponent()}
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
};

const BodyCase1 = () => (
  <div>
    Modal Body Case 1
  </div>
);

const BodyCase2 = () => (
  <div>
    Modal Body Case 2
  </div>
);

class App extends React.Component {
  
  state = {
    showModal: false,
    case: 1,
  }
 
  toggleModal = () => {
    this.setState({ showModal: !this.state.showModal });
  }
  
  toggleCase = () => {
    const nextCase = this.state.case === 1 ? 2 : 1;
    this.setState({ case: nextCase });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <button
          onClick={() => this.toggleModal()}
        >
          Toggle modal
        </button>
        
        <button
          onClick={() => this.toggleCase()}
        >
          Toggle next case
        </button>

        <FlexibleModal
          isOpen={this.state.showModal}
          headerTitle="Customizable Modal Header Title"
          renderBodyComponent={
            this.state.case === 1
            ? () => (<BodyCase1 />)
            : () => (<BodyCase2 />)
          }
        />
      </div>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('react'));
```

```css
.flexible-modal {
  margin: 15px;
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  background: #fff;
}

.flexible-modal-header {
  border-bottom: 1px solid #ddd;
  padding: 10px;
  background: #e7e7e7;
}

.flexible-modal-body {
  padding: 10px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>

<div id="react"></div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the elaborate answer. Still seems more or less what i did, just with different construction, doesn't it? Perhaps i'm missing some key difference though.

Comment: @sheff2k1 Yes, the key is that `renderBodyComponent` prop is used to pass your content to the `Modal`s body. I just made it a little bit more clear. Also, I don't recommend you chaining ternary operator `condition ? case1 : case2` as your code becomes harder to understand.

Comment: Yes...i don't know why i even used this ternary operator...there's nothing like good old "if else" :D

Comment: Well, there wasn't much to "solve", i just wanted to see if i can get better ideas...anyway i've checked your solution as the accepted answer.